# Is the a way run pyqt on micropython?

Tags: micropython

I want to know is it possible to run pyqt5 on micropython(pyboard),I think micropython library is too small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pyQT is **not** an option here. Read following discussion [here](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=5543) to find and choose suitable GUI lib for your micropython project.

From my personal experience- [my choice](https://github.com/lixas/SmartHome-Central) was [LVGL library](https://github.com/lvgl/lv_binding_micropython) for small ILI9341 touch screen.

Comment: Which GUI lib is powerful  in micro-python?