# How can i import the pico pi into python3 and execute micropython code safed on the pico from python3?

Tags: python, user-interface, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

Ive got a Pico PI and i want to program a GUI for it.
Since micropython doesnt support any GUI's like tkinter I was wondering if there is a way to Call and execute programms saved on the pico from python3.

thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the a way run pyqt on micropython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68870927/is-the-a-way-run-pyqt-on-micropython)

Comment: Call micropython programs from Python3 running where? Is Python3 running on a Linux machine with an attached Pico? Or something else?

Comment: You can communicate with the Pico over a serial connection, so you can certainly have Python on your host computer communicate with Micropython code running on your Pico.